# Explain the working of compare predicate of standard library sort function C++?

Tags: c++, function, sorting, c++11

After reading some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372132/c-stl-sort-function-binary-predicate) on stackoverflow I still couldn't understand when will compare function has to return false and when will it return true. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45929522/8092124) answer it is written that it models the less than operator but still what I think now is that if compare function is like:

```
bool compare(const myClass& object1, const myClass& object2)
{
     if(object1.property < object2.property)
         return true;
     else
         return false;
}
```

will sort a vector of `myclass` objects in ascending order. Am I right?...I think I'm still confused.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: This is basically fine, but a few improvements: Make parameters const reference (`const myClass&`) and function body can be one-liner: `return object1.property < object2.property;`.

Comment: Actually here it can be one liner but my application demands some preprocessing to compare the objects according to its property and then return the result in an if-else manner....that's why I've written it like this :) Btw thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The "less than" operator is sufficient to define a strict order. Eg. `a < b` is the same as `b > a`. Further, `(a < b) || (b < a)` defines `a != b`. Then `!((a < b) || (b < a))` defines `a == b`. Combine to get `<=` and `>=`, and you have full coverage from just one operator.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't write code like `if(condition) return true; return false;` (or with else as yours), just write `return condition;`; and if you return `false` in if clause, invert condition (`return !condition;`).

Comment: @Aconcagua I know but please read my above comment for my clarification :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While refering to standard is fine, understanding it can sometimes be quite hard...

Trying in simpler words:

If you want to sort elements, you need some kind of order relation that defines which of two elements shall come first ("be the smaller one"). Some data types come with a natural order, such as integral numbers, for instance: -12 < -10 - 0 - 10 < 12. `std::sort` (without comparison parameter) uses this natural order to sort elements ascending.

The third parameter gives you the possibility to tell `std::sort` explicitly how this order shall be defined, imagine the following:

```
std::vector v({12, 7, 10});
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int x, int y){return x > y;});
```

Looks unnatural, doesn't it? `std::sort` interprets the comparison as "less", but we implemented a "greater"! By doing so, the greater values then (as considered being "smaller") are sorted in front of smaller ones (considered being "greater"), so we have achieved sorting in *descending* order...

So the comparison parameter passed to `std::sort` is used to either sort differently to what the natural order would be or to define explicitly an order for data types where such order does not exist.

Side note: The order relation does not necessarily have to be a total order; however, equivalent elements then can be sorted in arbitrary order (you could, though, use `std::stable_sort` instead to at least preserve their relative order before sorting):

```
int a[12, 7, 10, 7];
std::vector<int*> v({&a[0], &a[1], &a[2], &a[3]});
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int* x, int* y) { return *x < *y; });
// v[2] == &a[2]
// v[3] == &a[1]
// BUT:
// v[0] == &a[1] && v[1] == &a[3] || v[0] == &a[3] && v[1] == &a[1]
```

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, read the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort#Parameters).

## comp -

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.
>
> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`
>
> The signature does not need to have const &, but the function object must not modify the objects passed to it.
> The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type RandomIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both of them. ​

Comment: Btw I couldn't find official documentation easily on searching. Mostly reference and other sites like cpluspus.com come in handy!